# How do you bind a Color to .fill()?

Tags: swiftui

I want to bind a color to fill.

```
.fill($color) // Instance method 'fill(_:style:)' requires that 'Binding<Color>' conform to 'ShapeStyle'
```

Do I need to create a custom `Binding` or something? I know I can do a ternary operation on a bound `Bool` and choose between two colors.. But I want to bind directly to `Color`.

Comment: You can directly use `.fill(Color.red)`, or `.fill(.red)`. Or you can create your own color set in your assets and give it a name, for example _**theme**_, then you can fill with your own color like: `.fill(Color("theme"))`.

Comment: @s3cret I needed binding so I can get any color that might come up

Comment: If `color` is a `State`/`Binding` object, then the `$` is unnecessary, and by only using `.fill(color)`, the view will already show the latest color that you have set to `color`.

Comment: Oddly that isn't working for me... perhaps I'm having a bug with Xcode or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your `color` is a `@State` or `@Binding` you can just use

```
.fill(color)
```

binding itself is performed automatically by SwiftUI engine - it detects used corresponding properties in `body` and refresh body whenever those properties changed.

Comment: Oddly that isn't working for me... perhaps I'm having a bug with Xcode or something

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer in Japanese on this persons [Blog](https://blog.kuromusubi.com/develop/language/swift/20200826-wrappedvalue).

```
.fill($color.wrappedValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to create a Color Set asset in Xcode for custom colors. You can name the color and use the color name in this way to create a fill:

```
Rectangle().fill(Color("FreshOrange"))
```

[image: Screenshot of Xcode color set asset]

Comment: Yeah that is nice if you have static colors. But dynamic colors also need to fill. But +1 for mentioning it here

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure that you didn't create a custom struct or class which is also named as Color?

If you accidentally use `Color` as a name for your own data types, then you can get a similar error which you've described.

For example, if you add the following struct, the project can still compile:

```
struct Color {
    var red: Float
    var green: Float
    var blue: Float
}
```

But when you would try to use it as a fill color, eg.:

```
.fill(Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0)
```

Then you would get the following error:

```
Instance method 'fill(_:style:)' requires that 'Color' conform to 'ShapeStyle'
```